# ReactJs check all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, select, reactjs

I have a select all component rendering in my table header, I would like it to check all of the checkboxes on the page when checked, if one of the checkboxes is unchecked I would like the select all to unselect too:

```
var SelectAll = React.createClass({

handler: function(e) {

    e.target.value;
    e.preventDefault();

    channel.publish({
        channel: "contact",
        topic: "selectAll",
        data: {
            contacts: this.props.data
        }
    });
},

render: function() {

    console.log(this.props.data.children);

    var id = this.props.contacts;
    var isSelected = this.props.data.isSelected;

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox" checked={isSelected}
                onChange={this.handler} />
        </div>
    );
},

});
```

My checkboxes are rendered in each table row:

```
var ContactSelector = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        selectedContacts:[]
    };
},

handleChange: function(e) {
    var id = e.target.attributes['data-ref'].value;

    if (e.target.checked === true){
        contactChannel.publish({
                    channel: "contact",
                    topic: "selectedContact",
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    }});
    } else{
        contactChannel.publish({
            channel: "contact",
            topic: "deselectedContact",
            data: {
                id: id
            }});
    }
},

render: function() {

    var id = this.props.data.id;
    var isSelected = this.props.data.IsSelected;

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox"
                checked={isSelected} data-ref={id}
                onClick={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}

});
```

Can anyone please tell me how to setup the check all? Using state or refs etc

Comment: side question: what library are you using for the channel.publish lines in this code?

Comment: https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js